# How to save the matlab workplace variable including original file name?

Tags: matlab, save

I would like to know how I can save the matlab output files (i.e. matlab workplace variables), by including original file name.

e.g. I open a file (filename.mat) with load filename.mat. Then I run a code to do calculation and I get some workplace variables (e.g. flow, pressure). I want to save those variables as filename_flow.mat and filename_pressure.mat.

I will use the same code on different filename, so I would like to know how I can save my variables as mentioned above (i.e. including the original file's name)?

Comment: I just assumed in my answer you actually mean a `.mat` file, because that's how MATLAB saves variables.

Comment: yes, sorry for my typo. I mean .mat file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FileToBeLoaded = 'filename.mat';
[pathstr,filename,ext] = fileparts(FileToBeLoaded) 
load([filename ext]);
%// calculate stuff
FlowVariable = %// some calculation
save([filename '_flow'],FlowVariable)
```

The same of course works for other names as well. You pull apart the original file name to its actual name and extension, and use the original name, add something (`_flow` in this case) and save that. The default of MATLAB is already to save to a .mat file, so that's taken care of automatically.

Comment: I'd recommend using [`fileparts`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileparts.html) and, where paths are concerned, [`fullfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html) for a more generalized and robust approach to generating the filename.